# How do I access a route parameter in my ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, routes

I have an URL like this `/home/action/id`

How can I access this id in view?

Comment: Jack, did you really change parameter to paramter in the title?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This should work in your view:

```
<%= this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] %>
```

(assuming the route parameter is named "id")

Comment: is this potentially vulnerable, since you aren't doing any check on the parameter?

Comment: @Jack: yes, probably. It is not guaranteed that a view is always invoked by using the same route, so the value for "id" might be missing.

Comment: This is vulnerable to a reflected XSS attack. It relies on the rendering middleware to filter out such attacks and should be used with EXTREME CAUTION. Lot's of answers to this question on SO without the proper disclaimer as to exactly how big of a security vulnerability this is. Reflected XSS attacks are a VERY serious vulnerability. While I applaud the answer for acknowledging this in the comments I would still urge that the answer be edited to point out the risk this poses to both users and site owners.

Answer (score 13):

you can pass it in through viewData;

In your Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    ViewData["Name"] = Server.UrlEncode(id);
    return View();
}
```

In your View:

```
<h1><%= ViewData["Name"] %></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, in MVC is more simple.

You can access `RouteData` values like this:

```
(ID <code>@RouteData.Values["id"]</code>)
```