# How to get input parameter in Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Example**

When editing item

```
/domain.com/app/item/detail/111     
OR
/domain.com/app/item/detail/?Id=111
```

When creating a new item

```
/domain.com/app/item/detail/new
OR
/domain.com/app/item/detail/
```

Comment: Not clear what you asking here. And what does razor have to do with your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access a route parameter in my ASP.NET MVC view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380867/how-do-i-access-a-route-parameter-in-my-asp-net-mvc-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access query strings like this

```
@if(Request.QueryString["Id"] == "111")
{
    <div>foo bar</div>
}
```

**or**

use ViewBag in your controller to give the information to the view

```
public ActionResult Detail(string Id)
{
    ViewBag.Id = Id;

    return View();
}
```

Then in your view

```
<div>@ViewBag.Id</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
Request.Params["paramName"]
```